# VLC h265 failure to display

Tags: linux, video, linux-mint, vlc-media-player

In VLC 2.2.1, an MKV file fails to show video, playing audio OK.

Error message:

> Codec `hevc' (MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265)) is not supported.

http://pastebin.com/7duQbH6S has the verbose debug log.

Hardware is a Lenovo T410, with a Core i5 CPU M 560 @ 2.67GHz and i915 Intel Graphics, running Mint Cinnamon 17.1 . I can see there's no 3D support for acceleration with the i915, but I do not see that 2D acceleration is not supported.

How may I resolve this?

How may I either resolve this, or find a video player which will play the video under Linux Cinnamon Mint 17.1 ?

Comment: Does the output of `vlc --list` show a decoder for x265? Perhaps your build of vlc/libavcodec doesn't have x265 support enabled? Not sure if libavcodec can be out of date if VLC is up to date, but it is worth checking.

Comment: I have the same problem. My `vlc --list` shows an HEVC/x265 demuxer, but I'm still not getting image, and the exact above error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [mpv](https://mpv.io/) player, it's a fork of mplayer2 with updated versions of codecs. VLC is often way behind on format support, because of outdated `ffmpeg`. On Mint you should be able to use either [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests) or [Debian testing](https://packages.debian.org/testing/mpv) builds:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mpv
```

Another option would be using [libde265](https://github.com/strukturag/gstreamer-libde265) from their [Ubuntu packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Estrukturag/+archive/ubuntu/libde265), however this might require newer version of VLC than is present on your system.

Comment: its `sudo apt install mpv`